# Передать переменную в keyboard.hook

Tags: python

```
def print_pressed_keys(e):
    if e.event_type == "down" and e.name == "1":
        print(str+"1")
    elif e.event_type == "down" and e.name == "0":
        print(str +"0")


str = "test"            
keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)
keyboard.wait()
```

Моя программа ожидает нажатия кнопки и должна выводить `str + 1` или `str + 0` в зависимости от нажатой клавиши. Вопрос в том, как передать str в  `print_pressed_keys`

Comment: для начала - `str` - это зарезервированное слово для обозначения встроенного метода python, поэтому придумайте переменной другое название.  Затем, что мешает вам передавать свою строку в функцию так же, как вы передали туда параметр `e`?

Comment: обычно в функцию я передаю параметры так `function(param1, param2)` но здесь для меня не очень понятная конструкция `keyboard.hook(print_pressed_keys)` не очень понимаю как сюда можно, что то передать

Comment: Ваш вопрос не понятен. Покажите что вы получаете сейчас и покажите что вы хотите получить.

Comment: мне нужно передать переменную `str` в  `print_pressed_keys`

Comment: Вам уже писали, что для названия переменной `str` - это не хорошо. Объясните лучше, зачем вам передавать переменную?  У вас что возникает какая-то ошибка?